# How can I store a function, local to one class, in another class?

Tags: python, function, dictionary, class

I have two classes, Window and Page. Each page has a unique id. I have some functions in the Page class called `self.render_page1()` and `self.render_page2()`, which I want to store in the Window class in a dictionary, like this: `self.pages = {"1":render_page1, "2":render_page2}`, with the key being the id of the page. I want to be able to grab the value from the dictionary in the Window class to then be able to call the function in the Page class.

My current code is:

```
class Window:
   def __init__(self):
      self.pages = {"1":(Page("1", self), render_page1), "2":(Page("2", self), render_page2)}

class Page:
    def __init__(self, id, window):
        self.id = id 
        self.window = window
        self.display_page()

    def display_page(self):
        self.window.pages[id][1]()

    def render_page1(self):
        pass

    def render_page2(self):
        pass
```

The issue I believe is that the `render_page` subroutines are local to the Page class so they need to be stored differently in the Window.

Comment: You can prefix them with `Page.`

Comment: Are you trying to make each `Page` object have its own `render_page` method?

Comment: However I'm a bit confused about why are you doing so

Comment: When you init your window with two pages you probably want to do `p1 = Page("1", self)` then you can `self.pages = {"1":(p1, p1.render_page1)}`. However, since `self.pages[1]` is already `p1`, do you need to store the render method? Can't you get to it via `self.pages[1][0].render_page1`?

Comment: @matszwecja my current solution has it that each `Page` object has every `render_page` method, it just only calls the one that it needs. But if there was a way for each `Page` object to have only the `render_page` method that it needs then that would be ideal.

Comment: Sure there is a way. I'm not sure why each page object would require a separate render method.

Comment: @alexniem Just to be clear, `render_page1`, `render_page2`, etc are all doing the same, but you created them separetely to be able to refer to them in `Window`?

Comment: No, they each do something different. Thats also why each object requires it's own method

Comment: @alexniem In that case they probably shouldn't be of the same class. Each instance requiring a different method is a clear sign of something wrong with class structure.

Answer (score 0):

in python, there are a number of ways to call a method indirectly. If you have

```
class A:
    def some_func(self):
        ...
```

you can store a tuple `object, method_name` and call it with `getattr`:

```
tup = A(), 'some_func'

# later on

obj, name = tup
getattr(obj, name)()
```

or you can store a pointer to the method and call it with an object as the first arg (known as `self`):

```
tup = A(), A.some_func

# later on

obj, fn = tup
fn(obj)
```

or you can simply store `object.method` and call it later on as an ordinary function, thanks to the python auto-binding feature:

```
stored_fn = A().some_func

# later on

stored_fn()
```

Answer (score 0):

Because those functions are inside the `Page` class's namespace, you should access them using the `Page.` prefix.

However, I think I don't quite understand why you need this. If your goal is get the pages by id and call the methods based on different `Page` objects, you can store the "Method" object instead of a function. A method object as a reference to the `Page` instance. So no need to store the instance separately.

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Any, Callable, TypeAlias

Method: TypeAlias = Callable[..., Any]

class Window:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pages: dict[str, Method] = {}

    def add_page(self, page: Page, method_name: str) -> None:
        bound_method = getattr(page, method_name)
        self.pages[page.id_] = bound_method

class Page:
    def __init__(self, id_: str, window: Window):
        self.id_ = id_

    def render_page1(self):
        pass

    def render_page2(self):
        pass

window = Window()
page = Page("1", window)
window.add_page(page, "render_page1")
```

Another would be to pass id and method object directly to `add_page` method:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Any, Callable, TypeAlias

Method: TypeAlias = Callable[..., Any]

class Window:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pages: dict[str, Method] = {}

    def add_page(self, page_id: str, method: Method) -> None:
        self.pages[page_id] = method

class Page:
    def __init__(self, id_: str, window: Window):
        self.id_ = id_

    def render_page1(self):
        pass

    def render_page2(self):
        pass

window = Window()
page = Page("1", window)
window.add_page(page.id_, page.render_page1)
```